# Ambiguous reference of system call sync()

Tags: linux, include, system

I am trying to write the cache before I call the reboot() in my c++ method..WHen I compile, I get the error that the reference 'sync' is ambiguous. THe one I am using is defined in "include " and our thirdparty include cil library that brings in another sync() functions. How do I get to pint to the unistd.h version?

Comment: Show your code. Did you `#include <unistd.h>`?

Comment: #include <unistd.h>                                                                                             static const int s_RebootOptions = LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF;
    sync();
    reboot(s_RebootOptions);

Comment: Please **edit your question**. Code chunks take four spaces at start of their line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you might use `::sync();` if you want to refer to the global [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) (see [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/) about global variables in C++); you'll need to `#include <unistd.h>` appropriately.

You can't put statements in a global scope in C++; statements should occur only inside function definitions.

I also suggest to avoid calling [reboot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) just after one `sync();` since I believe that the `sync` might not complete. Perhaps

```
 void restart_the_system(void) { // a C++ function
   ::sync();
   ::sleep (1);
   ::sync();
   ::sleep (1);
   ::sync();
   ::reboot (LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF); 
 }
```

might be slightly better. But these days, your Linux is probably using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) and you should use it to reboot.

Comment: yeah I have these in a function that I haven't fully copuied as the editor in not very graceful